# EditPlus doesn't have find-file-by-name functionality?

Tags: text-editors

A friend of mine has used EditPlus for over 5 years and says he never finds file by a name.

Is there no such functionality in that editor? (I find this hard to believe!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. The trick is to search for 'anything' in the files and choose a filetype that matches the kind of files that you are looking for.

- Open the `Find in Files` dialog box
- Make sure that `Regular expression` checkbox is checked
- Enter `.*` in the `Find What` field
- In the `File Type` field enter the kind of files you're looking for. For example:

  - `*.java` to search for all java files
  - `Comment*.*` to search for all files that start with 'Comment'